# Geometric interpretation of left-singular and right-singular vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I wanted to ask if and how

$A^{T}A$ respectively $AA^{T}$

can be interpreted geometrically in the sense of it's eigenvectors being the left and right singular vectors? What is the geometric interpretation of left and right singular vectors?

Thanks for any answers.